# C source in .W file

Tags: c, linux, unix, latex, tex

I found a C source in these files with `.w` extensions.  It seems like a mix of TeX code
and C Programming Language.  [This](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/programs/spiders.w) is an example of these sources.

How can I compile?

PS: Excuse me for the silly question but I didn't found any documentation

Comment: Woa, strange stuff... now I'm curious too! :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use Knuth's CWEB, a literate-programming tool.  You can download it from [here](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/cweb.html).